# Sencha Architect 2 - how to edit code

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

I am using `Sencha Architect 2`. I need to know how i could edit the code using the IDE. i clicked on the `code` tab but the code is in `readonly` format. How can i edit this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 set's of code in SA.  The code that's generated for you and the code that you add.  To add you need to drop in event handlers (basic event bindings), functions, controller references, etc ...

In the code view there is a drop down with all of the items that contain code.  Some of them may be editable depending on what type of class your looking at (view, controller, store, model).

I imagine your looking at the generated class (not directly editable).  You add things to it by dropping behaviors http://cl.ly/0A0J1v1Q2O3C17233w10

Answer (score 1):

sencha architect code cannot be manually edited if you wish to do so then go to the metadata folder where you saved the project and over there you can manually edit the files then come back and save in architect which will overwrite the existing files

Comment: for example, i edited the app.js file, and added additional code into it. When i open the project by clicking on the `.xds` file, the changes i made to the app.js file were not picked by the IDE.

Comment: @sharonHwk: If you're just adding additional functions, why not do that from the Inspector?  It has the ability to add arbitrary functions with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what Phil has said Sencha Architect only allows you to edit configs... If you are looking to edit properties in views you additionally need to create overrides and in the override you can modify the property like this

```
config: {property-name: { 
    //whatever you want to change}}
```